# 2001 Honda Civic - random no-start, fixed by battery disconnect

Tags: honda, starting, civic

My wife has a 2001 Honda Civic that's been very reliable for us. Just this past weekend it wouldn't start. We took the battery and the starter in for testing and all tested fine on the bench. Suspected ignition switch, but after putting battery and starter back in, it started fine. Suspected loose connection maybe?

Then after using all weekend with no issue, it wouldn't start this morning. You turn the key, get one click and then everything in the car is completely dead. Pulled key out of ignition and tested lights. Nothing worked. Disconnected battery ground, and went and made a pot of coffee. Came back and reconnected and the car started fine.

Suspect some sort of computer module or security issue? Nothing after market in the car. Thanks for any help in advance.